# Прикрепить картинку относительно фона

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Привет всем, есть тестовый сайт. Можно ли как-нибудь прикрепить яблоко к руке, так чтобы оно не двигалось при масштабировании страницы, а оставалось только в руке или это не возможно?

```
css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background:  url(../images/bg3a.jpg) #eaeaea no-repeat center top fixed;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

#imgapple {
  margin-top: 230px;
    width: 220px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 570px;
}
```

Comment: @Анютааа, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Для этого можно сделать яблоко непосредственно фоном body. Свойство `background-position` поможет поставить его на нужное место.

Вообще, для таких рисунков отлично подходит `<svg>`. И с позиционированием проблем не будет, и качество лучше, и размер картинки меньше будет (если только вы не будете добавлять много отдельных элементов).